# using app.yaml to host a small static website

Tags: windows, google-app-engine, web-hosting

I'm currently trying to host a small static website on google's app engine but am running into problems correctly configuring app.yaml.

My application directory:

> [folder] applicationname
>
> [subfolder1] static
>
> ```
> [subfolder2] css //stylesheets
>
> [subfolder2] js //scripts
>
> [subfolder2] img //images
>
> [subfolder2] files //this contains additional html files
>
> Index.html
>
> About.html
>
> Portfolio.html
> ```
>
> app.yaml
>
> favicon.ico
>
> index.yaml
>
> main.py

My app.yaml currently holds the following information:

> application: applicationname
>
> version: 1
>
> runtime: python
>
> api_version: 1
>
> handlers:
>
> -url: /img/(.*)    static_files: static/images/\1    upload: static/images/(.*)
>
> handlers:
>
> -url: /css/(.*)    static_files: static/stylesheet/\1    upload: static/stylesheet/(.*)
>
> handlers:
>
> -url: /js/(.*)    static_files: static/javascript/\1    upload: static/javascript/(.*)
>
> -url: /(.*.html)    static_files: static/\1    upload: static/index.html
>
> -url: /.*    script: main.py

When I try to run the page, I get the follow error message:

> Host: appengine.google.com
>
> Error parsing yaml file:
>
> Duplicate attribute 'handlers'.
>
> in "I:\5 - HTML\kaoartwork\app.yaml", line 14, column 1
>
> 2012-07-24 13:00:21 (Process exited with code 1)
>
> You can close this window now.

Whatever help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well, the error is right there, you have multiple handlers.

Answer (score 1):

you are declaring handlers 3 times in your app.yaml.
there is only one needed on top of your handlers definitions.

```
application: applicationname
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:

<your handlers here>
```

Comment: I've fixed the handlers now but the app engine seems to still have problems finding my index.html. I believe this is because my urls under handler are not linked correctly. Is there anything I can do about this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: replace `/(.*.html)` with `/(.*\.html)` . you need to escape the `.`